# Question about つらい after verb

Tags: grammar

I read the definition of the word 苦しむ:

> 肉体的な痛みや苦しさを感じてつらいと思う

I don't understand what the つらい is doing there. Does it mean the same as づらい. Is there any difference between them?

If so, then I interpret it as "To think "hard to feel body-pain and pain"", is that correct?

Comment: づらい is added to a ます-stem, not a て-form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's after the て-form, つらい doesn't apply to the verb.

〇〇感じてつらい doesn't mean "it's hard to feel". It means "it's tough because I feel 〇〇".